# Evanescent waves in Vacuum

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I would like to know why [evanescent waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evanescent_field) are not possible in pure vacuum?

Indeed, we have $$ k^2 = \left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2 $$

in vacuum, so we could have for example : $$ k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2=\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2 $$

with $ k_z=i k_z'' $ and $ k_x^2+k_y^2 > \left(\frac{ \omega } {c}\right)^2$.

I have read that we need local charges to do it but I don't understand why.

Comment: What is your formal definition of "evanescent wave"? The term is difficult to nail down as people seem to have some kind of aversion against actually writing down a definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refraction: Energy flow, tunneling and Evanescent EM waves](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216892/)

Answer (score 1):

Evanescent waves appear as boundary conditions; vacuum solutions lack boundaries, except at infinity.

S  < https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evanescent_field>

Comment: I understand that if I have two medium with n1>n2 it is possible to create a wavector along the x axis in medium 1 that will be larger than the allowed wave vector in the medium 2. So the kz will for example be imaginary in the second medium => evanescent wave.

But here, it explains that If I am at the interface between two dielectric I can have evanescent wave in the second if I properly choose my angles.

But it doesn't explain why in vacuum it can't happen also.

If we don't add any condition on $ k^2=(\frac{w}{c})^2$ in the vacuum nothing forbid to have evanescent wave in vacuum.

Comment: When you work the problem you will find that either the evanescent field will vanish, or it will be a transient.  Evanescent fields are very important in some applications,  such as fiber optics. Working a few problems is always worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

When we study diffraction in optics, we use the angular spectrum of plane waves and indeed, the evanescent waves in a vacuum are components of this spectrum when the sum of the squares of the direction cosines is greater than 1. This is treated in Goodman's book about Fourier optics. Doing a quick search, I found the following link: [Angular Spectrum Method](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/BSc_Optics_(Konijnenberg_Adam_and_Urbach)/06%3A_Scalar_diffraction_optics/6.04%3A_Angular_Spectrum_Method)

Hope it can help.